# Problem with printbibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing my thesis (for which I found a template online), divided into different files: main, Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc, which I include as soon as I write them, as follows:

```
\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
%\include{Chapters/Chapter5}
```

The part related to the bibliography is - I think - only the following:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=ieee-alphabetic, sorting=nty]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{main-Bibliography} 
\usepackage[autostyle,english = british]{csquotes}
```

and, at the end of the main, I have:

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

Now, my problem seems to lie in the third chapter, as when I include all the others, everything works fine. In this case, when I compile, I get the following message:

1: section

```
[14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20] [21]
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }
                 
l.277 \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

?

If I remove `\printbibliography`, all the citations are well displayed, so I can't understand if the problem lies in my bibliography file or in my third chapter.

From what I wrote, is anybody able to understand where the problem is?

Thank you very much in advance
William

Comment: It is probably a problem with one of your bibliography entries. Presumably one of the entries contains a character like `_`, `^`, `$` that needs or starts math mode and needs to be escaped when it should appear literally.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll check

Comment: You should use `\addbibresource{main-Bibliography.bib} `. Do you have any news for us? Is the issue solved? How?